# xTable Knitr Error - every line is printed underneath in PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, xtable

I try to knitr my R-Markdown as PDF and want to print some tables using xtable, but unfortunately I print every item of my table underneath: [Print Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3kRD.png)
(FYI: I'm in college and asked to use xtable for this exercise).

I use the following code (there are more tables but they follow the same pattern;
the library xtable is already loaded in my R-Markdown earlier):

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
swisstable <- sapply(swiss,function(x) {
c(Mean = mean(x), SD = sd(x), Median = median(x), IQR = IQR(x))
} )
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
swisstable <- xtable(swisstable,align=xalign(swisstable),digits=xdigits(swisstable), 
display=xdisplay(swisstable))
```

```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
print(xtable(swisstable, digits = 1, caption = "Tabelle 2: Überblick über den Datensatz 
swiss"),type='html')
```
````

I'm grateful for any help,
thanks,
Martina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to knit in a pdf keep `results='asis'` and don't print `xtable`.

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
library(xtable)
swisstable <- sapply(swiss,function(x) {
   c(Mean = mean(x), SD = sd(x), Median = median(x), IQR = IQR(x))
 })
```

```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
  xtable(swisstable, digits = 1, caption = "Tabelle 2: Überblick über den Datensatz swiss")
```
````

[image]